# Index & Match 2 different data sheet for multiple column in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have two different data sheet and would like to compare multiple column. If is match then return value 1.

I have tried with formula below and seems not working..Anyone know the reason or advise the correct formula instead.
**=INDEX('[Cancellation Raw Data 2023.xlsx]Sheet1'!$Y:$Y,MATCH(G2,'[Cancellation Raw Data 2023.xlsx]Sheet1'!$X:$X,0),MATCH(J2,'[Cancellation Raw Data 2023.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C:$C,0),MATCH(R2,'[Cancellation Raw Data 2023.xlsx]Sheet1'!$F:$F,0))**

Attached below screenshot below for reference.
Highlighted Yellow = Matching this 3 columns
Highlighted Green = expected result if is match to show value 1 in Book1 excel sheet
[image]
[image]

Comment: Every reference in the formula that you provided refers to columns in `[Cancellation Raw Data 2023.xlsx]Sheet1!`. And in your 2nd screenshot, the spreadsheet clearly has only 1 sheet as well. Can you clarify which columns you want to match with which exactly? Moreover, it is not clear what you mean by "value 1", do you mean return 1 as a value? or is the name of the column "value 1"?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have [dynamic arrays](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) then this must be entered as an array formula (using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
=INDEX('[Cancellation Raw Data 2023.xlsx]Sheet1'!$Y2:$Y10001,MATCH(G2&J2&R2,'[Cancellation Raw Data 2023.xlsx]Sheet1'!$X2:$X10001&'[Cancellation Raw Data 2023.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C2:$C10001&'[Cancellation Raw Data 2023.xlsx]Sheet1'!$F2:$F10001,0))
```

(it's best to avoid full-column references, so I've assumed you have just 10k rows of data - you should adjust the references for your actual number)

Comment: The formula is work, however I noticed the excel keep loading and calculating the threads if my data list is huge. Any way to solve this matter?

Comment: @Cheng, you can switch Calculation mode (from the _Formulas_ tab) to manual while both tables are still being updated, and then use the _Calculate Now_ (or F9) option to update the formulae when all data entry are complete.